# Join on table with common part in jsonb in nested array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am having hard time trying to figure out this join.
I have two related tables:

`Reservations`

```
 id | data                 
----+------------
  1 | something
```

`CalendarEvents`

```
 id |                 relates_to                                      | time
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"type:": "", "relations": [{"#type": "", "relatesToId": "1"}]} | "2022-02-02"
```

I'd like to select Reservations and all CalendarEvents matching them by id, like this (simplified)

```
SELECT r, ce FROM reservations r
LEFT JOIN calendar_events ce ON r.id = ce.relates_to.relations.relatesToId
WHERE ce.time > '2022-01-01';
```

`relates_to` is in jsonb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first unnest the JSONB array using `jsonb_array_elements`. You can do this using a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, which you can place inside the `JOIN`, allowing you to use it as part of the join condition

```sql
SELECT r, ce
FROM reservations r
LEFT JOIN calendar_events ce
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(ce.relates_to->'relations') rel(relation)
  ON r.id = (rel.relation->>'relatesToId')::int
WHERE ce.time > '2022-01-01';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C3esuPbJ)

Note the use of `->` to retrieve `jsonb` and `->>` to retrieve `text`. You also need to convert the text to `int`

Comment: Thank you very much!